Class-Validator: I want to apply custom validator only if built-in validator pass
class RegisterBody {
  @IsEmail()
  @IsEmailRegistered()
  email: string;

  @IsStrongPassword()
  password: string;
}

I want to apply IsEmailRegistered only if IsEmail pass and always run IsStrongPassword (I don't want to use stopAtFirstError).

import { IsEmail, IsStrongPassword, ValidateIf, ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface, ValidationArguments } from 'class-validator';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IsEmailRegisteredValidator', async: true })
export class IsEmailRegisteredValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(email: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    // Your logic to check if the email is already registered
    return true; // or false if email is already registered
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Email is already registered.';
  }
}

class RegisterBody {
  @IsEmail()
  @ValidateIf(o => o.email !== undefined) // Only validate if email is defined and passed IsEmail validation
  @IsEmailRegisteredValidator()
  email: string;

  @IsStrongPassword()
  password: string;
}


thank you,
I have tried this and two validators is applied when email property is exist and two validators is ignored  when email property is not exist.
